# C# run VBScript with MSScriptControl AddObject with string failed

Tags: c#, vbscript, msscriptcontrol

This is my C# program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CallVbsFunction(1); //Work
        CallVbsFunction(1.2); //Work
        CallVbsFunction('a'); //Work
        CallVbsFunction("a"); //!!Exception see bellow
    }

    private static void CallVbsFunction(object p)
    {
        var sc = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
        sc.Language = "VBScript";
        sc.AllowUI = true;

        try
        {         
            sc.AddCode(System.IO.File.ReadAllText("script.vbs"));
            sc.AddObject("myguid", p, false);
            var parameters = new object[] { "a" };
            sc.Run("test", ref parameters);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

My VBScript file contents:

```
Function Test(a)
    MsgBox myguid
End Function
```

And Finally this is my exception when I use AddObject() with string object:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A0005): Invalid
>   procedure call or argument    at
>   MSScriptControl.IScriptControl.Run(String ProcedureName, Object[]&
>   Parameters)    at Srcipting.Program.CallVbsFunction(Object p) in
>   Program.cs

Comment: The single quotes version is passing a `char` wheres as the double quotes is passing a `string` which is an _array_ of chars

Comment: Yes my problem is when I use String, I know VBScript use VARIANT and BSTR, If I call  MsgBox typename(myguid) is returning "String" but not work.

Comment: What happens if you use `sc.AddObject("myguid", p[0], false);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a wrapper object that is `ComVisible`:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class StringWrapper
{
    private string wrappedString;

    public StringWrapper(string value)
    {
        wrappedString = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return wrappedString;
    }
}

CallVbsFunction(new StringWrapper("a"));
```

The problem is that the .net String object looks like a native vb string to the MSScriptControl on the first look but not on the second look.

---

You only need to use this wrapper when you register a string directly or register a function that returns a string. There is no problem when registering an object that has properties of type string. There is also no problem for the parameters you pass to `Run()` because these will be correctly marshaled to native vb strings by the .net runtime.

---

So the maybe best option is to not provide individual strings to your script but an object that encapsulates all the different values you want it to use.

Define this class

```
[ComVisible(true)]
public class HostOptions
{
    public string OptionA { get; set; }
    public string OptionB { get; set; }
}
```

Then construct the object and set all the properties and register it with the script control

```
var hostOptions = new HostOptions();
hostOptions.OptionA = "AAA";
hostOptions.OptionB = "BBB";

sc.AddObject("HostOptions", hostOptions, false);
```

You can then use it in your script like this:

```
Function Test(a)
    MsgBox HostOptions.OptionA
    MsgBox HostOptions.OptionB
End Function
```

Comment: I don't really understand "the .net String object looks like a native vb string to the MSScriptControl on the first look but not on the second look.". But you solution work for me.

Comment: I don't know the details, but this is what it looks like to me.